# Total used memory - free memory

Tags: c#, memory, dealloc

I have some problem with memory allocation.
For example:

```
            long mem1 = GC.GetTotalMemory(true); 
            //mem1 = 2954648
            using(StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(url_File))
            {
            // File size ~ 350MB
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    AkcjaSeries.Data.Add(AkcjeRecord.Parse(sr.ReadLine(), columnDescription, datePattern, separators));
                    linesCount++;
                    if (linesCount%100000 == 0)
                    {
                        textBox.Text = linesCount.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            textBox.Text = linesCount.ToString();
            long mem2 = GC.GetTotalMemory(true); // = 760587356
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();    // I use all this method 
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); // beceuse i realy need free memory
            GC.WaitForFullGCApproach();    //
            long mem3 = GC.GetTotalMemory(true); // = 760587356 (the same as mem2)
```

and class look like:

```
  public class AkcjaSeries : ObservableCollection<AkcjeRecord>
  {
    public static AkcjaSeries Data = new AkcjaSeries();

    public const int MaxElementsInChart = 100;

    private String name;
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
  }
```

and

```
   public class AkcjeRecord : DependencyObject
  {

    public static readonly string[] Separators = { "\t", " " };

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(AkcjeRecord));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CostProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Cost", typeof(double), typeof(AkcjeRecord));

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(DateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DateProperty, value); }
    }

    public double Cost
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(CostProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CostProperty, value); }
    }

    public static AkcjeRecord Parse(string line, int[] columnDestination, string dataPattern, string[] separators )
    {

        AkcjeRecord akcjaRecord = new AkcjeRecord();

        string[] dividedLine;

        dividedLine = line.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        akcjaRecord.Cost = Double.Parse(dividedLine[columnDestination[0]], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        string dateAndTime = dividedLine[columnDestination[1]] + dividedLine[columnDestination[2]];

        DateTime date;
        TimeSpan time;

        date = DateTime.ParseExact(dividedLine[columnDestination[1]], dataPattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        time = TimeSpan.Parse(dividedLine[columnDestination[2]]);


        date = date.Add(time);

        akcjaRecord.Date = date;

        return akcjaRecord;

    }
```

@QUESTION

Why when i calling methond 
         GC.Collect(); 
i dont have any effect of this. (i write comments how many memory program need)
What i'm doing wrong? 
By the way... i only take 60% data per row 
File row example :

```
    20100729    09:34:15.948    70.07   167022  319
```

(i parse  only 1, 2, 3 column)

Comment: What memory are you hoping to free? `AkcjaSeries.Data` is a static field, and you just filled it with stuff.. What makes you think there's anything to free?

Comment: Also, passing `true` to `GetTotalMemory` allows the GC to collect before returning.

Comment: `GC.Collect()` requests the GC to clean up the *managed heap*. That may or may not release memory to the OS. Remember the CLR tries to be smart about memory handling. Allocating and freeing memory is costly, so the CLR doesn't do this for every managed allocation/cleanup.

Comment: so explain me why program in c# cost ~750 MB RAM
(this same program written in Delphi cost ~90MB )